# Доступ к переменным из функции

Tags: php

У меня есть файл `functions.php`, в котором есть функция, которая парсит json-строку, декодирует её и возвращает массив в качестве аргумента функции `return $response;`. Я подключаю этот файл к index.php посредством `require('php/functions.php');` в начале файла, а затем пытаюсь сделать вывод элемента массива:

```
echo $response['name'] . ',+' . $response['country_name'];
```

Но у меня возникает ошибка `Notice: Undefined variable: response`. Объясните, почему так происходит? Ведь если я подключаю файл с какими-то функциями к индексному файлу, это подразумевает, что функции должны подгрузиться в основной файл? И как мне получить доступ к переменной в функции?

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть функция, которая может принимать(или не принимать) что-то на вход и отдовать что-то на выход. То, что внутри функции отдаётся значение какой-то переменной это не значит, что переменная будет доступна из вне. К тому же, функцию надо вызвать, чтобы получить результат. И присвоить его какой-то переменной.

Происходит что-то вроде этого:

```
public function foo($a) {
    $response = 'json чего-то там:' . $a;
    return $response;
}

//а теперь вы пытаетесь использовать $response и вылетает ошибка.
//Т.к. область видимости переменной $response только внутри функции foo()
//нужно примерно так:
$myResponse = foo('hoho');
// $myResponce будет равен 'json чего-то там:hoho'
```